# R-Raster: Increase spatial resolution from 50 meter to 30 meter

Tags: r, tiff, r-raster

I have a raster of 50 meter resolution. I am trying to make it to 30 meter.
I tried with raster::disaggregate function, but the resolution is not changing to 30 meter.

```
library(raster)

a = raster("file.tif")

b = disaggregate(a, fact=30/50, method='bilinear')
```

It would be really helpful if you have some alternative solutions. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `disaggregate` function expects an integer for the `fact` argument. You can use the `resample` function instead. I'm using some sample data because I don't have yours so you will need to modify this for your environment. I'm resampling 40 by 40 to 5 by 5 to make the plots show up with differences.

```
library(raster)
rr <- raster(system.file("external/test.grd", package="raster"))
res(rr) # 40 by 40
#[1] 40 40
# Create a raster to aim for - make sure its projection is the same as the original and
# uses metres.
proj4string(rr)
#[1] "+proj=sterea +lat_0=52.1561605555556 +lon_0=5.38763888888889 +k=0.9999079 +x_0=155000 +y_0=463000 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs"
ss <- raster(resolution=c(5,5), crs=proj4string(rr), ext=extent(rr)) 
res(ss) # 5 by 5
#[1] 5 5
rs <- resample(rr, ss) # This makes a new raster with the 5 by 5 resolution
res(rs) # should be 5 by 5
#[1] 5 5
```

40m by 40m...
[image]

5m by 5m...
[image]